# ANTLR - Can I Have A Parser For QTI-Based JSON Data / Grammar

Tags: java, gwt, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to implement the IMS QTIv2.1 spec for AssessmentItem (questions) in a computer-based-testing web application I am developing with GWT. Thing is, data (questions) in the QTI standard are encoded and delivered in an XML format which I intend to convert to JSON for lighter transportation. This data describes how the app is to render the question and score it after the candidate makes an attempt.

So my question is, can I use ANTLR to parse and interpret such JSON encoded QTI data so that my app (web / HTML5 mobile) can display and handle the questions accordingly.

Comment: The answer is probably "yes". I have no idea how the Java to JS conversion of GWT will go. You'll simply have to try to find out.

Comment: BTW, how did you produce/converted your JSON?

Comment: I just used an online tool, but I don't think that will be a coding issue in Java.

Answer (score 0):

JSON grammar is just [a dozen or two of productions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.8), so *of course* you can build a JSON parser with ANTLR.

But most probably you should not. This is 2014 now, so writing your own low-level parser for JSON (this is what you'll get with ANTLR) has a strong "reinventing the wheel" flair.

I'm not sure, what would work with GWT best, but here's a couple of "usual suspects" when it comes to JSON processing on the server side:

- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Since your data comes in XML and there's probably an XML Schema for it, then definitely do check [Jackson/JAXB](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) combo. This would allow you to unmarshal XML into POJOs and marshal them as JSON.

---

My [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/) library could do the similar thing (XML Schema driven XML<->JSON conversion) on the client side. You could generate XML<->JSON mappings and parse your QTI data from XML into JSON structures directly on the client. I am not sure if this is suitable for your case and including this just as a hint.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/) library mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But I really don't want to (at this time) consider processing the data on the server, because it (QTI) does not just encode the questions but how a rendering engine is to display it and how entries are scored. So I think the encoded questions should be wired to the client for now (web or mobile) which can then display them, accept entries and score the candidate. Another thought is to just render on the client but score on the server (meaning app cannot be offline) because the scoring part is where I was really looking at ANTLR. Closely consider  http://goo.gl/oO8kMo